# The equivalence of $p \rightarrow (q\rightarrow p)$ and $p \rightarrow (p \lor q)$

Tags: logic

How is 
$p \rightarrow (q\rightarrow p)$ equivalent to $p \rightarrow (p \lor q)$ ?

My attempt
p→(~q v p)
I don't get how did the answer came (this is a question in my textbook)

Please respond ASAP!

Comment: Okay I'll respond: ASAP!

Comment: Please not that P and p are distinct.  It seems you mean the same thing by them.

Comment: They were the same sir

Comment: Do you know what truth tables are?

Comment: Yeah..I know how to do them...I tried building one ...and yes the statement seems to be true...but I want an algebraic method instead

Comment: You do know that $q \rightarrow p$ is equivalent to $\neg q \vee p$.  Apply the same rule to the outside implication.

Comment: I don't get you.. could you show that properly fabio ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $ q \rightarrow p$ is equivalent to ~$q\lor p$ so it simplifies  to $ p \rightarrow ($~$q\lor p)$ now this is also equivalent to ~$p \lor($~$q\lor p)$ which is again $ p \rightarrow (p \lor $~$q)$

Comment: Yeah I totally agree ...this is what I did but the answer is p→(pvq)

Comment: I think there is some typo in the question.

Comment: Probably... Still Thanks a lot navin...